# Daily Ubuntu freezes following certain behaviour

Tags: audio, bluetooth, freeze

Sorry if I'm not formatting this question correctly - I've never used StackExchange before - but I need some help with my Ubuntu freezes/crashes.

Since getting this distro (and especially since getting Regolith) I've been having a great experience on my laptop, and have been finding that I'm using a lot less memory and other system resources than I used to making all my programs run smoothly. However, for some reason, my system completely freezes almost every day at this point with no functionality whatsoever (not even allowing REISUB), leaving me with no choice but to hard reboot it every time. I generally don't lose much work and can get started again quickly, but I know doing this kind of thing a lot can really damage a system.

While I'm not entirely sure what the cause of this is, I have noticed that it always occurs after a few minutes or more of inactivity, and soon after returning to the laptop pressing the 'Play' button in an application such as RhythmBox or LMMS. Does anyone know why this might be, and how I could fix or avoid it?

Thanks in advance, Dominic

Comment: Can you login to your laptop via SSH? Please try.

Please check system logs for kernel errors via `journalctl -k`

Comment: I think you should be more specific about the problem and less talking about your nice experiences with Ubuntu. More relevant would be e.g. the things Artem S. Tashkinov wrote, or what kind of hardware you are using. From your description the issue could really be anything. Also this question may be more appropriate for the http://askubuntu.com/ site.

Comment: Maybe this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/248676/pc-freezes-after-long-period-of-inactivity-30-min

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - Thanks for the advice, I have since checked the logs but unfortunately there wasn't anything helpful on there for this particular crash.

Comment: @alphanum - Sorry if I didn't post the question in the correct format or on the right site. I commented on my nice experiences to show that there didn't appear to be system resource problems compared to my previous operating system (Windows ._.) which didn't have any serious issues like this, but maybe I should have been more explicit in stating that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is a late reply, I was doing a lot of testing to make sure I'd fixed the problem and forgot to check back on this. It turns out the Bluetooth speaker connection was messing up the system for some reason, so I tried connecting the speaker to my laptop headphone port manually (with a certain type of wire, I've forgotten what it's called now though). After a few days of playing music, videos, etc I haven't had a single crash, and I'm not even getting the slight audio jittering that used to be happening  (;

I know this isn't really a fix, as clearly there's something wrong with the Bluetooth drivers or Acer hardware. However, I'm finding this solution satisfactory, and I hope it'll help anyone with problems like mine who looks at this in the future.

Comment: Good find, does not sound like an obvious one!